# Add additional field in forgot_password.jsp in liferay

Tags: java, liferay, struts, action

I created a hook and added one additional field in `forgot_password.jsp`. My problem is how to handle it.I read I should create an action and the action I should change is `ForgotPasswordAction.java`. I don't know much about struts and I am new to liferay. Do u know how to make this input in `forgot_password.jsp` works:

```
<aui:input label="<%= firstName %>" name="<%= firstNameParameter%>" size="30" type="text" value="<%= firstNameValue%>">
    <aui:validator name="required" />
</aui:input>
```

I guess I should get the name from here:

```
User user2 = (User)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.FORGOT_PASSWORD_REMINDER_USER);
```

but what I should put in firstNameParameter? From where I should get it?

The point is to add a field to forgot_password.jsp to make the user write his first name in order to change his password. This is additional requirement to this page. Here is source of forgot_pasword.jsp: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/login/forgot_password.jsp

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you adding another field and ask us how to name it? Or how to handle it on the action side? Please describe the underlying business case in addition to the code that you quoted - maybe another approach is even better...

Comment: my question is how to handle it on the action side.

Comment: crossposted here https://www.liferay.com/en_GB/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/60106407